# CRLF vs LF vs zero on network protocol design

Tags: string, encoding, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols

I am designing a private networking protocol. I need to choose a delimiter of strings.

The packets will look like `string01\0string02\0string03\0` if the delimiter is `\0`

The string is not only ascii, it is any end user defined encoding string, like utf8 or base64 encoded binary data.

My purpose is to make a flexible and small size protocol, so the string should support some kind of compress algorithm. I wonder if the delimiter is important for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the encoding is end-user defined, it could contain `\0` bytes such as UTF-16, so perhaps a run length-encoded string would work best:

```
\x08string01\x08string02\x08string03
```

Or if you need strings longer than 255 bytes, choose a 2-byte (max 65535) or more big-endian (convention for network protocols) value:

```
\x00\x08string01\x00\x08string02                 (ASCII)
\x00\x10\x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00n\x00g\x000\x001 (UTF-16BE)
```

Comment: Maybe I should force to use utf8 encoding.  if so, \0 is OK

Answer (score 0):

Besides length encoding, which was already proposed by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen), you can also use an escape character. You set a delimiter character (say \0) and if \0 appears in the data, you put a special "escape character" ahead of it, to escape its special meaning. This is used by some protocols such as HDLC:

> ...they use "control-octet transparency", also called "byte stuffing" or
>   "octet stuffing". The frame boundary octet is 01111110, (7E in
>   hexadecimal notation). A "control escape octet", has the bit sequence
>   '01111101', (7D hexadecimal). If either of these two octets appears in
>   the transmitted data, an escape octet is sent, followed by the
>   original data octet with bit 5 inverted. For example, the data
>   sequence "01111110" (7E hex) would be transmitted as "01111101
>   01011110" ("7D 5E" hex)

Comment: Note that you also have to escape the escape character itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would assume the strings format (ie ASCII or UTF8 or whatever) by the version of the protocol. Version protocol I think you should be part of the protocol handshake (initialization). For example:

```
 1. Client opens TCP connection to Server 
 2. Server> \x... <-- magic
 3. Server> \x01 <-- Protocol version 
 4. Client> \x00 <-- Ok
```

And then rather use string termination for strings use data size header prior string send like:

```
Client or Server> 0x000f <-- following data will be 100 bytes
Client or Server> .... // 100 of raw data is being transmitted and then decoded using the right encoding that is protocol coupled.
```

I think this way the protocol is much easier to understand easier to extend.